# Two dates in php script

Tags: php

When I am processing two dates within a php script, the output that is rendered is not what is being expected.

For example when I run

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('EST');
$firstday = date('Y-m-01');
$today = date('Y-m-d');

if ($firstday = $today)
    echo "Today is the 1st <br/>";
else 
    echo "Today is not the 1st <br/>";

echo'The first of the month is: '. $firstday . '<br/>';
echo'Today is: '. $today . '<br/>';
?>
```

The output is:

> Today is the 1st
>
> The first of the month is: 2014-07-30
>
> Today is: 2014-07-30

When it should be

> Today is not the 1st.
>
> The first of the month is: 2014-07-01
>
> Today is: 2014-07-30

However when I run one of the date()s at a time, I get that $today = 2014-07-30 and I get $firstdate = 2014-07-01 but not when I run them at the same time.

Can you not run two date() functions at the same time in PHP or do I have it formatted wrong?

Comment: `if ($firstday = $today)` <-- you use `=` instead of `==`.

Comment: Was just going to say that ^^^ you're assigning instead of comparing. Plus, use braces man.

Comment: Wow. Duh. I had that before and I must had accidently deleted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't assign $today to $firstdate or vice-versa
Do $firstday == $today

```
date_default_timezone_set('EST');
$firstday = date('Y-m-01');
$today = date('Y-m-d');

if ($firstday == $today)
    echo "Today is the 1st";
else 
    echo "Today is not the 1st";
```